# Можно ли создать экземпляр интерфейса и объявлять в интерфейсе делегаты?

Tags: c#, делегаты, интерфейс

Вопрос по C#: Можно ли создать экземпляр интерфейса и объявлять в интерфейсе делегаты?

Comment: @Roman Surntest, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Понятие "экземпляр интерфейса (instance of an interface)" как таковое не корректно! Интерфейс не может содержать в себе реализацию, не является объектом и служит для того что бы задавать поведение объекту (классу).

Но тем не менее существует способ откомпилировать вот такой вот код:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    //Some methods
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
     IFoo iFoo = new IFoo();
}
```

Это становится возможным когда для интерфейса мы задаем [CoClassAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.coclassattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). Простыми словами этот атрибут используется для указания типа "совместного" класса и взаимодействия с ним с помощью интерфейса. Использование CoClassAttribute тянет за собой также использование атрибутов [ComImportAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comimportattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) и [GuidAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Полный код выглядит так:

```
[Guid("9D1752A0-BA61-43C6-AA6A-25674A5F1032")]
[CoClass(typeof(Foo))]
[ComImport]
public interface IFoo
{

}

public class Foo : IFoo // Хотя для компиляции реализация этого интерфейса не обязательна - получите в runtime InvalidCastException, но обязательна для работы
{

}
```

Таким образом, когда мы делаем запись в виде:

```
IFoo iFoo = new IFoo();
```

Дальше очевидно, на самом деле создается экземпляр класса Foo, т.е. как бы мы писали:

```
IFoo iFoo = new Foo();
```

P.S. Такое использование можно встретить, например, в interop сервисах MS Office:
[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.application.aspx)

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
```

Answer (score 3):

Экземпляр самого интерфейса создать нельзя. Но можно создавать экземпляры классов, его реализующих. Добавлять делегаты в интерфейс нельзя, но можно добавлять события

Comment: немного не по вопросу, но в абстрактный класс можно добавлять делегаты?

Comment: @Roman Surntest скажите, а что вам мешает взять компилятор и самому проверить это? По вопросу - да, можно